# How to change Code Style on WebStorm/IDEA

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea, npm, webstorm

This is the code style used on my current JavaScript project:

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
, b: 2
, c: 3
}

var arr = [
  'a1'
, 'a2'
, 'a3'
]

const w = 1
  , w2 = 2
  , w3 = 3
```

They say they are using [npm's coding-style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style).
And I'm trying to configure my [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) IDE to use it, but I cannot find or create the correct configuration. WebStorm keeps fixing me all those commas.
E.g. this code:

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
, b: 2
, c: 3
}
```

WebStorm transforms to this:

```
var obj = {
  a: 1
  , b: 2
  , c: 3
}
```

Please help me to do it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Comma First](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style) section of the npm-coding-style contains this example:

```
var magicWords = [ 'abracadabra'
                 , 'gesundheit'
                 , 'ventrilo'
                 ]
  , spells = { 'fireball' : function () { setOnFire() }
             , 'water' : function () { putOut() }
             }
  , a = 1
  , b = 'abc'
  , etc
  , somethingElse
```

I get the impression that the preferred style for your `obj` variable could be (similar to the `spells` variable above):

```
var obj = { a: 1
          , b: 2
          , c: 3
          }
```

[WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) might be able to handle this style.